# Присвоение суб-домена виртуальным машинам

Tags: домен, поддомены, виртуальная-машина

Добрый день!
Я новичок в этих вопросах , так что заранее извиняюсь если этот вопрос глупый)

Есть сервер. На нём n-ое кол-во виртуальных машин. На этих вм стоит томкат и каждый разворачивает сайт (то есть, есть 4 сайта). Я получаю к ним доступ по локальной сети, и пробросив порты , через интернет.

```
    ВМ 1 - 1.1.1.1
    ВМ 2 - 1.1.1.2
    ВМ 3 - 1.1.1.3     (локальная сеть)
    ВМ 4 - 1.1.1.4
```

Внешний ИП - 10.10.10.10

- ВМ 1 - 10.10.10.10:81
- ВМ 2 - 10.10.10.10:82
- ВМ 3 - 10.10.10.10:83    (доступ к развёрнутым сайтам через интернет)
- ВМ 4 - 10.10.10.10:84

Я хочу обращаться к моим развёрнутым сайтам с помощью суб-доменов (домен domen.ru куплен). Но , при создании суб-домена я могу ввести только ip , без указания порта (то есть , только 80 порт).

Возможно ли реализовать суб-домены для каждой вм с одним внешним ip ?

Comment: Какая ос на хостовой машине?

Comment: Hyper-V Core 2012 R2

Comment: VM - Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Можно. Используйте, например, nginx, который в зависимости от имени сайта будет редиректить запросы по виртуалкам.

Comment: Могу посоветовать поднять отдельную виртуальную машину, на которую прокинуть весь домен на 80 порт. На данную виртуальную машину поставить nginx (возможно можно придумать что-то и с томкатом, но я с ним не работал) и уже внутри nginx пробросить линки на другие виртуальные машины.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное !)

Comment: Пока что смог реализовать это добавив 

server {
server_name sub1.domen.com;
rewrite ^ https://10.10.10.10:81$request_uri permanent;
}
Можно ли избежать "открытых в мир" сайтов ?

Comment: Вернее , чтобы не нужно было открывать порт для каждой вм

Comment: Решено через proxy_pass

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо [Alexander](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/193407/alexander) и [kff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194374/kff).

Хочу оформить, вдруг у людей будет похожий вопрос. Подняв ВМ с NGINX , все ваши суб-домены попадают в него. Откуда , добавив конструкцию в файл `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (в блок http) :

```
server {
  server_name sub1.domen.com;
  reset_timedout_connection  on;
     location ~* / {
       proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1;
     }
 }
```

Вы получите желаемый результат. Возможно это не лучший способ, но в моем случае работает.